# How to hide Windows Phone ad in a legitimate way, so that it doesn't receive impressions

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, adview

Just decided at the last minute to display ads in various pages of my Trial app.

Below is the xaml that I'm adding to the bottom of my pages:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ad_stack" Margin="0,0,0,4">
            <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80"  
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" 
 ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

IN the codebehind, I have this, to catch ms pubCenter issues, such as no ads in a region, and in that case, display adMOb:

```
 private void AdControl_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        AdControl ad = (AdControl)sender;
        StackPanel grd = (StackPanel)ad.Parent;
        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            AdView bannerAd = new AdView
            {
                Format = AdFormats.Banner,
                AdUnitID = "myidhere"
            };
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
            grd.Children.Add(bannerAd);
            bannerAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        });
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
     }
```

My main question is .. 
  when a User purchases the App, 
  and thus my App's IsTrial boolean is false,

How to **hide** the Ad completely, not only visually, but so that neither MS or Google is registering any impressions from it.

If I simply set the adControl to visibility.collapsed, that would turn off MS' Ad (I'm new at this, so guessing that), but then Google's adMob might show.

Referring to the XAML I posted above, can I simply set the StackPanel, named "ad_stack", to Visibility.collapsed, or would that cause pubCenter and/or adMob to still receive impressions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the documentation for both ad providers. But failing that, rather than changing the `Visibility`, just remove them from the tree altogether (`ad_stack.Children.Clear()`) and they will get unloaded. Or, better yet, don't even add them to the tree until you know the user is a trial user.

Comment: Thanks, but question on this,

In order to dynamically add it to tree based on the isTrial value, I'm guessing I won't be able to implement the XAML code I included at the top here?  

Sounds like I would need to do it in C# instead.

Comment: Oh nevermind, found the way to do that:

http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2012/12/05/using-the-adcontrol-from-code-in-windows-phone-8.aspx